# Deserialize xml or json from Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to Deserialize files in Azure File Share but the closer I got is using the ShareClient, ShareFileClient and using the DownloadAsync() method. But this doesnt allow me to deserialize as I cant convert it to a Strem object.

How I am supposed to read/Deserialize files in Azure File Share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would still use [`DownloadAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.sharefileclient.downloadasync?view=azure-dotnet) method which will give you the download result in [`ShareFileDownloadInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.models.sharefiledownloadinfo?view=azure-dotnet). The contents of the file will be available in [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.models.sharefiledownloadinfo.content?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharefiledownloadinfo-content) property which gives you a stream that you can use any way you see fit.